# Script for parsing a biological sequence from a public database in Python

Tags: python, text-processing, bioinformatics, biopython

Greetings to the stackoverflow community,

I am currently following a bioinformatics module as part of a biomedical degree (I am basically a python newbie) and the following task is required as part of a Python programming assignment:

extract motif sequences (amino acid sequences, so basically strings in programmatic-speak, that have been excised from algorithms implementing a multiple sequence alignment and subsequently iterative database scanning to generate the best conserved sequences. The ultimate idea is to infer functional significance from such "motifs").

These motifs are stored on a public database in files which have multiple data fields corresponding to each protein (uniprot ID, Accession Number, the alignment itself stored in a hyperlink .seq file), currently one of which is of interest in this scope. The data field is called "extracted motif sets".

My question is how to go about writing a script that will essentially parse the "motif strings" and output them to a file. I have now coded the script so that it looks as follows (I don't write the results to files yet):

```
import os, re, sys, string 

printsdb = open('/users/spyros/folder1/python/PRINTSmotifs/prints41_1.kdat', 'r')

protname = None  
final_motifs = []

for line in printsdb.readlines():
 if line.startswith('gc;'):
        protname = line.lstrip()    
        #string.lower(name)  # convert to lowercase
        break

def extract_final_motifs(protname):

"""Extracts the sequences of the 'final motifs sets' for a PRINTS entry.
Sequences are on lines starting 'fd;' A simple regex is used for retrieval"""

for line in printsdb.readlines():
        if line.startswith('fd;'):
                final_motifs = re.compile('^\s+([A-Z]+)\s+<')
                final_motifs = final_motifs.match(line)
                #print(final_motifs.groups()[0])
                motif_dict = {protname : final_motifs}
                break 
return 

motif_dict = extract_final_motifs('ADENOSINER')
print(motif_dict)
```

The problem now is that while my code loops over a raw database file (prints41_!.kdat) instead of connecting to the public database using urllib module, as suggested by Simon Cockell below, the ouput of the script is simply "none" on the python shell, whereas it should be creating a list such as [AAYIGIEVLI, AAYIGIEVLI, AAYIGIEVLI, etc..]

Does anybody have any idea where the logic error is? Any input appreciated!!
I apologize for the extensive text, I just hope to be a clear as possible. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe crosspost this on Biostars.org: A Bioinformatics oriented stack exchange site: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, will try biostars then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of what you are doing is almost right but you have to change `"extracted motif sets"` lien 2 to a variable say `line` . What the `for` loop will do is to return data form the file line by line as the variable after `for` this case `line`. And now comes the question how the `lysozyme.seq` file is formated. its sounds like that none of the data fields have any spacing. Then that means you might get away whit doing `line.split(" ")` or `line.split("\t")` `\t` meas tab. the split will do what it says it dose split the string every time it sees a `" "` or `"\t"` depending on what you write in the program.

Saning directory to find the files shouldn't be to hard theres probably some questions here about it.

If you post data or a part of in form one of the files so we can have a look at it the we might be able to help you pars it :).

Comment: Hello and thank you for the comments. lysozyme.seq, or ----.seq as a generic file name for the database, is formatted, as far as I can tell, in ASCII. It is a gapped, color-coded alignment with avg. 10 protein sequences (basically strings). The data fields, located in a separate file which has a hyperlink to the alignment (----.seq) file do have spacing because it is (mostly) sequence data meant to be presented in human-readable format. I will post an example of the data field to give a better idea of what I'm attempting to do. Thanks again for the advice :P

Comment: It's really hard to give advice how to handle data whit out knowing how it looks :P But pm me when you have put up some samples.

Comment: For formatting reasons, I post a link to the type of database file I am working with.  http://www.bioinf.manchester.ac.uk/cgi-bin/dbbrowser/PRINTS/DoPRINTS.pl?cmd_a=Display&qua_a=/Full&fun_a=Code&qst_a=ADENOSINER.  What I would like is basically to parse the sequences (strings of capital letters) under the data field "FINAL MOTIF SETS". I would need to be able to do this in a systematic way since there are a couple hundred files on this database.  The "view alignment" hyperlink at the very top next to the name is where the alignment is located (.seq file)

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that **your function does not return value**? That's the reason for None.